# Google spreadsheets, arrayformula queries

Tags: google-sheets

I have two questions.

Question #1:
I am using this formula =SUM(E2,F2,G2,H2) for D2 cell.
Where E2, F2, G2, H2 are numbers
I want to repeat this formula for the whole D column. Please help me how to do this.

I see there is ArrayFormula, but I am confused how to use it, since I am not getting any results if I use

For e.g.
I tried,
=arrayformula(E2:E+F2:F+G2:G+H2:H)
But the answer is coming wrong.

Question #2:
I am using this formula =CONCATENATE(N2,O2,T2,U2,AJ2,AK2,BF2,BG2,CH2,CI2) for J2 cell.
Where N2,O2,T2.. all are strings
I want to repeat the same formula to whole cells in J3, J4 etc. automatically when the user enters the data.

I don't even know how to try this. Please help me by proving your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your first formula seems to work correctly, although if you want to hide zeroes on blank rows then try this formula in cell D2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E+F2:F+G2:G+H2:H=0,"",E2:E+F2:F+G2:G+H2:H))`

To concatenate within an arrayformula, try using the & sign:

`=ArrayFormula(N2:N&O2:O&T2:T&U2:U&AJ2:AJ&AK2:AK&BF2:BF&BG2:BG&CH2:CH&CI2:CI)`